# Best practice for designing user/roles/people in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I would like to know how is the best way to design tables in database in the next scenario:

I have companies, clients and employees with some common fields and others are totally different. The most important thing is all of them have a username, email and password to be able to login in an admin system. Then I would like to know the best way to organise all that data in tables. At the moment I was thinking

- **user (id, role_id, email, username, password)**
- **user_role (id, parent_id, name)** -- company|client|employee
- **user_role_link (user_id, role_id)**
- **company (id, user_id, name, ...)**
- **client (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, ...)**
- **employee (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, start_date, end_date, ...)**

That way I have only to check the table user when the user login but I don't know if is a company, client or employee (I have to check all tables).

I am a little bit confuse about this then I don't know how to do it...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have a user_role table (which seems like a reasonable idea), then I can't really see any point in having a role_id column in the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about getting rid of the `user_role` and `user_role_link` tables, since you already have the required information in the other tables and then you don't have to maintain all these links:

```
user (id, email, username, password)
company (id, user_id, name, ...)
client (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, ...)
employee (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, start_date, end_date, ...)
```

Note there is no such thing as "role" anymore, because clients, companies, and employees "have a" user.  So what you have is an aggregation model in the above.

Going further than this, what you might be proposing is an object-oriented inheritance approach.  Seen through that filter, you would just have user, company, client, and employee, where the latter three are "kinds of" users.  In fact company, client and employee can actually share the same IDs with user in this case since they are essentially the same object!  They are all derived from user and are users.  (But unless you know what you're doing I wouldn't necessarily advise this option.)

So those are the two options I see here - aggregation or inheritance.

Notice if you lose the link tables, you can still figure out which type of object you have by doing an outer join on all three of the tables and checking which table's ID field comes back with an ID as opposed to a null.  Once you know the type you have, the type-specific code has very straightforward querying, with just a single join, `user` to whichever derived table.  For example, let's say you know you have a `client`, the `client` code can query directly against the `client` table and just do one join to user and that's all that's needed.

For more information on some common ways of laying out object-oriented data in a conventional database, the reference material on Python's SQLAlchemy provides some general approaches:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/

SQLAlchemy is a library that is specifically designed to aid with object-relational mapping issues, so you can see how they do things.  I'm suggesting this as a reference for that reason, and not for any Python connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way. I create a Profile table... and users/employs/clients use it.
And an user should be get a role. If do you want create users groups, you need create a Users Group Table.

Table "user":
    id_user
    date_created
    date_deleted
    id_role
    id_profile
    username
    alias
    password
    password_question
    password_answer

```
Table "role":
id_role
date_created
date_deleted
name (35)
description

Table "permission":
id_permission
date_created
date_deleted
name
description

Table "permission_assigned":
id_permission_assigned
date_created
date_deleted
id_permission
id_user
id_role

Table "user_session":
id_user_session
id_user
logon_date
logoff_date
ip_address (45)
user_agent (413)

Table "profile":
id_profile
date_created
date_deleted
first_name (35)
last_name (35)
sex
email (254)
phone (15)
birthday
address (40)
id_country
id_state
id_city
zip_code (10)
description
```